# Asp.net throwing random error

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net blog that is randomly throwing this error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

It lasts anywhere from 5 minutes to 1 hour.

I haven't implemented error logging yet, but in the meantime what can cause this? The error goes away on it's own after a while.

Thanks.

Comment: ask your hoster if any problems

Comment: Something in your code, faulty memory module, god? It could really be anything. You need to investigate more and logging is a good first choice.

Comment: Already asked my hosting, waiting for a reply.

Answer (score 3):

Check your windows Event Log, specifically the Application log.  Uncaught ASP.NET errors will show up there.

Comment: It's hosted externally, Im just wondering if this error could be something specific.

Answer (score 3):

Use Elmah, it is available as nuget package, in 2 minutes you will have an error logging enabled application. So you can view and detect error.

Elmah has lots of features and easy to integrate. You can follow these link for more info.

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx

http://nuget.org/packages/elmah

Comment: Yes yes I know about it, this is what I am doing.